# Group mysqli/PDO results by category and display them into groups

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I am trying to create a simple gallery that gets the data from a mysql table.

My idea is to have Gallery like this

```
Category 1:
Image1         image2      image3 .. so on
Category 2:
Image4         image5 .. so on
```

My table structure looks like as below:

`Category Table`

```
id   cat_name   status
------------------------
1    Category 1   A
2    Category 2   A
```

`Image Table`

```
id   catID   image   status
----------------------------
1     1       A.jpg   A
2     1       B.jpg   A
3     1       C.jpg   A
4     2       D.jpg   A
5     2       E.jpg   A
```

I tried Query like as below:

```
class Gallery_Photo extends Model {

 public function photosGallery()
 {
    $result = $this->query('SELECT * FROM photos WHERE status = "A" ORDER BY pcID ');
            return $result;
 }
}
```

But it is not Working. Any ideas how to display as desired?

Comment: what does that mean?? Why you need my PDO class.. I asked a basic question and you are not meat to be rude here

Comment: I am not rude. It s just that your class and explanation cannot be understood. Post the complete script and class and we might understand better your problem as of right now it s not understandable.

Comment: I guess this is more about a simple mysql query involving a join between 2 tables and a group by. Having it in an extended class the way you do it without proper pdo prepared statment is pure none sense and totaly overkill...

Comment: then u please give your solution and i will confirm

Comment: See joachim answer is a very good one regarding mysql. It s up to you to concat or not in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to get to what you're looking for is probably a simple `GROUP_CONCAT` which will give you a comma separated list of images per category;

```
SELECT cat_name, GROUP_CONCAT(image ORDER BY image.id) images
FROM category 
JOIN image
  ON category.id = image.catid
GROUP BY category.id

cat_name    images
-----------------------------
Category 1  A.jpg,B.jpg,C.jpg
Category 2  D.jpg,E.jpg
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c15d0/4).

Comment: i am getting Unknown column 'image' in 'field list'

Comment: @Gags Are your tables really called `category` and `image`? Your sample select says `photos`...?

Comment: i have renamed the tables to just test... but it is throwing error

Comment: @gags Is the field name with the image name called `image` as in the example? It seems to be that field that it cannot find.

Comment: My Bad... I was confusing image with table name and was wondering how i can GROUP_CONCAT table :D

Comment: If i have image description then can i get also that in this query

Comment: yup.. i got that.. Thanks :)

Comment: @Gags You could always group concat the description in the same manner, however you may want to pick another separator that isn't used in descriptions. (something like `GROUP_CONCAT(description ORDER BY image.id SEPARATOR '§')`) As long as you order by `id`, they will end up in the same order as the names.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP_CONCAT-based solution is rather ugly, as it requires the post-processing and - worst of all - will make it just painful when you will need not only image name but some other information like dimensions or a caption.

At the same time PDO has a ready-made feature, exactly for your case, called [PDO::FETCH_GROUP](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#group).

All you need is select the common field first, and the rest is unbelievable simple:

```
$sql = "SELECT cat_name, image FROM category c, image i WHERE c.id = i.catid";
$data = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

And you will have a nested array where keys will be category names and values will be arrays with images. So you need only two nested loops to complete the quest:

```
<? foreach($data as $cat_name => $images): ?>
    <?=$cat_name?><br>
    <? foreach($images as $row): ?>
        <img src="<?=$row['image']?>">
    <? endforeach ?>
<? endforeach ?>
```